# Is the stock heatsink/fan on this Core i5 adequate?

Tags: cpu, noise, cooling

I'm looking at a 65W Core i5 Sandybridge processor:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819115075

Is the stock heatsink/fan included with the unit adequate? If it is adequate, will it be excessively noisy?

I'm not planning on doing any overclocking.

Comment: Intel is betting a 3 year warranty the bundled fan is adequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stock cooler is actually rather quiet and not noticeable when inside case.
I just build a media PC with that exact i5 for my family room.

Also found this: 
http://lanoc.org/review/energy-items/4638-intel-i5-2500k-sandy-bridge